# Set-SPSiteAdministration cmdlet - owner user alias

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to update a site collection owner using SharePoint cmdlet `Set-SPSiteAdministration`. The below code:

```
Set-SPSiteAdministration -Identity "http://contoso/sites/testsite" -OwnerAlias "dc001\spadmin"
```

Updates the site owner. This works and the 'site collection primary administrator' field is updated, e.g. [image](https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/images/SharePointOnline-UserProfiles2.png). To confirm the update I use:

```
$Site = Get-SPSite "http://contoso/sites/testsite"
$Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators
```

The 'siteadministrators' property shows nothing. If I use the central administrator *web panel* to *manually* update the site admin, `$Site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators` works correctly.

This [technet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spsiteadministration?view=sharepoint-ps) page states the type must be a valid user alias (it is) and the data type `SPUserPipeBind`.

Is there an issue with passing a string? What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Start-SPAssignment -Global
Set-SPSiteAdministration -Identity "http://sp:12001/sites/pub" -OwnerAlias "contoso\userb"
$s = Get-SPSiteAdministration -Identity http://sp:12001/sites/pub | Select -Property OwnerLoginName
$s
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
```